# open a browser (without a window) in C++ and click on different buttons

Tags: c++, libcurl, google-chrome-headless

So i'm looking for a way to open a browser (don't really care which one but prefer chrome), WITHOUT a windows.
I want to write a c++ program which simulates filling the textbox and pressing the button without opening a browser or controlling mouse and keyboard movements.

To open a browser I found:

```
bool open_browser(const char* url, HWND parent = NULL)
{
    HINSTANCE result = ShellExecuteA(parent, NULL, url, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    return ((int)result > 32);
}
```

But it opens a window...

To navigate on the website afterwards, I found [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl.html) but I have no idea if it's the one I need to use.
OR 
I was thinking of CGI but no idea if it's possible.

Another idea is to connect to the server with sockets, but i don't know if it is possible and how to click on items after.

Thank you all for your answers, and hope it helps other then me

Comment: What you need is a programmable [headless browser](http://www.asad.pw/HeadlessBrowsers/). There are a bunch of options with different features and specific purposes.

Comment: yeah i already know selenium but i want to now if it's possible to go even faster then that and go threw sockets. I think it could work but it is much more work.

Comment: Well if you know the precise action you want to execute and you only want the resulting response from the server then yes, you can just send the corresponding HTTP(S) message and get the answer. `libcurl` is an option. For C++ you have others like [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) networking libraries, [Boost.Beast](http://www.boost.org/libs/beast) or [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/).

Comment: Well I need to find what to execute that is the problem. I don't have the infos yet. I will have them when the page gets updated.
I need to use parser that tells me when the item is released, and when the parser finds it, it clicks on it.
I already did a program in python with selenium and headless chrome. now I want to do it in c++ so it is more powerful. But no clue how to do that. 
In libcurl, can we click on a button or something like that? (or parse the html website)
thank you for your answers @jdehesa

Comment: I mean if the button is just a form POST or something like that you can just parse the page but if you need to get the result of something done by the page using Javascript or similar you either have to use a full web engine (headless browser) or replicate the Javascript logic in your code (e.g. ajax requests, Javascript computations, etc, maybe cumbersome, [browser dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) may help a bit).

Comment: with what can I parse the page really fast? libcurl does it? if it does then i have the solution to me problem

Comment: libcurl only deals with the HTTP protocol communication. For parsing you can try an XML library, although HTML is frequently not fully correct XML, so maybe better a specific tool like [gumbol](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) or [MyHTML](https://github.com/lexborisov/myhtml) (couple of results from Google search). Or, if your case is not too complex, you may even make do with [regular expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) or similar.

Comment: thank you! i'm going to try that

Comment: @lucky simon, please tell me, if it's not a secret, what did you choose in the end - Libcurl or Headless Chrome ?